# Usage of FullCalendar mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, fullcalendar

Has anyone used the [FullCalendar-mobile](https://github.com/JordanReiter/fullcalendar-mobile#readme) plugin? I am trying to use this in a jQuery Mobile app bundled with Phonegap. There are tons of js and css files in the src folder but I can't seem to figure out which one to use. Linking all of them to my html page didn't yield any results.

Pardon the very noob question. Kinda new to jQuery, HTML5 & CSS. Would greatly appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code? Or create a fiddle (jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: have you looked at the documentation yet?

Comment: Yes I have read the documentation of FullCalendar. The steps for usage is simple in the documentation but the documentation is for the web plugin, not the mobile one. The mobile plugin didn't have a fullcalendar.js or fullcalendar.css files in the zip file, instead a number of js files and css files. Dunno which one to use and how.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just going through this myself. My understanding is that you'll need to do the following:

1. Download the files from
   https://github.com/JordanReiter/fullcalendar-mobile using either git
   or the 'download as zip' button.
2. Navigate to your downloaded directory
3. Type `make zip`, as per the instruction from the link above. (You'll need java installed apparently)
4. In the dist directory created by the above process you should see the fullcalendar directory containing the js and css files you need.
5. Copy those to your project and link appropriately. You are now officially good to go

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with the css files. Until now I'm not able to combine the style sheets delivered with jquery and jquery mobile for the desired result:

http://thomkerle.blogspot.ch/2012/07/problems-with-jquerys-fullcalendar-and.html

Note:
for basic usage you can just take the latest fullcalendar version! There will be some events that are not supported (but basically you can press on a event and navigate through the calendar).
See also:
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=23763

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use the _loader.js file
just keep the structure of the directories that exists

I am working on this right now ill post updates as a reference.  The documentation states:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar.css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='ui.core.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ui.draggable.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ui.resizable.js'></script>
```

None of these files are on github the last 3 are clearly from jquery UI